# coding error when using abline to add linear regression lines to each set of points in a scatterplot

Tags: r, lm

I could use some help for:

- adding the correct "best fit line", aka, `abline`to my plot

I have a two level factor variable called "Control", with corresponding data points in the column "consumption_mean"

I plot the two here, but try to add an `abline`and it does not yield the result I'm looking for at all (even the `col=`does not seem to work. I set it to red, it yields black.

Any help is much appreciated

I would like a red regression line through the red data points (when Control==1), and a black one through the black data points (when Control==0)

```
df_mean <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/C2dz6bDT", header = T)

df_mean$Control <- as.factor(df_mean$Control)

plot(df_mean$mean_consumption~df_mean$day, type="n")
points(df_mean$day[df_mean$Control=='1'],df_mean$mean_consumption[df_mean$Control=='1'],col='red',pch=15,cex=.8)
points(df_mean$day[df_mean$Control=='0'],df_mean$mean_consumption[df_mean$Control=='0'],col='black',pch=15,cex=.8)
abline(lm(df_mean$mean_consumption~df_mean$day+(df_mean$Control=='1'),lwd=1,lty=1,col="red"))
abline(lm(df_mean$mean_consumption~df_mean$day+(df_mean$Control=='0'),lwd=1,lty=1,col="black"))
```

Notice that not only are the lines **not** red, but the first regression, which is set for Control==1, actually doesn't fit the red points at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of things here,

1) Your lines are not turning red because you put the `col` and other arguments into the `lm` instead of the `abline` this can be fixed by moving one of the brackets.

```
abline(lm(df_mean$mean_consumption~df_mean$day+(df_mean$Control=='1')),lwd=1,lty=1,col="red")
```

2) Your lines and data points are not aligned because you are using different 'formulas' to plot them. your code should be similar to:

```
plot(x,y)
abline(lm(y ~ x))
```

For your case, 
`x` = `df_mean$day[df_mean$Control=='1']`; and 
`y` = `df_mean$mean_consumption[df_mean$Control=='1']`

so your `abline` should be

```
abline(lm(df_mean$mean_consumption[df_mean$Control=='1']~df_mean$day[df_mean$Control=='1']),lwd=1,lty=1,col="red")
```

---

After fixing all of the issues, you will get your desired plot:

[image: Desired Plot]

Comment: The ```col=```now functions (lines successfully change colors), however, they actually don't match the colors of the points on the scatter plot.  Try running the follow command for just the red dots (following your suggestion):


`plot(df_mean$day, df_mean$mean_consumption,type="n")

points(df_mean$day[df_mean$Control=='1'],df_mean$mean_consumption[df_mean$Control=='1'],col='red',pch=15,cex=.8)

abline(lm(df_mean$mean_consumption~df_mean$day+(df_mean$Control=='1')),lwd=1,lty=1,col="red")
`
I would like to fit a regression line the fits the red dots.. this one clearly isn't correct..?

Comment: @Andy, I have more thoroughly included the fix to your issue in my answer. Do you understand now how your `lm` formula was incorrect?

Comment: Hi

I do see why the formula was incorrect now. I ran the code, and get the same result as what you display here.  

All the best to you and thanks for your patience and explaining where I was going wrong.

Comment: @Andy, Glad I could help. Please consider "accepting" my answer with the check mark on the left. It will help others with similar problems in the future find an answer more easily.